# How to enable both this vim feature: mouse cursor move and paste with middle mouse in same time?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I would like to have two features in VIM

1. Mouse Cursor Movement
2. Paste from global clipboard with middle mouse

For the first feature I can set `mouse=a` and the second `mouse=r`.

Separately these features work but not together.

If I set `mouse=ar`

- mouse cursor move [OK]
- middle button mouse paste using information selected within vim [OK]
- middle button mouse paste using information selected from external app [FAIL]

Is it possible to get these feature in same time without install extra   applications /packages ?

`$ vim --version | grep clipboard
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard`

Thanks for your help

**Edit**
I was told that I can use shift+middle mouse button to paste from external selection. This could do the job, if there was a way to merge both internal and external buffer (selection).
In such case how to enter in insert mode when shift+middle mouse button is used ?

Comment: To paste external text in `xterm` you should use `ctrl+shift+v`, in fact most shorcuts needs to be altered with `shift` in order to work in a terminal emulator in linux. To enter insert mode in vim use the `insert` key.

Comment: About the insert mode, I am looking to add a trigger or an event handler from normal mode `nmap` which enter in insert mode paste primary buffer and come back to normal mode while using `shift+middlemouse`

Answer (score 1):

The [X Clipboard](https://mutelight.org/subtleties-of-the-x-clipboard) has interesting behavior. There are three selections, or *clipboards* if you will:

- `CLIPBOARD` : interact with `Ctrl-c`, `Ctrl-v`, or `Edit` menus.
- `PRIMARY` : interact with `Shift+Insert` or middle-mouse.
- `SECONDARY` : mostly unused and out of scope for this.

Not all terminal emulators support middle-mouse pasting, as alluded to by @dmb. In your case, the information that you're trying to paste with middle-mouse is being stored in `CLIPBOARD` which is not accessed via middle-mouse. However, understanding *where* your information is being copied *to* will help you in understanding how to extract that information. Beyond that, I suggest you find a clipboard manager that provides a satisfactory workflow.

Comment: You can find a solid list of clipboard management software here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard#Managers